# Remove ul indent - solutions found not working?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-lists, indentation

I've read many questions regarding the same issue... but it just won't work for me. I'm just messing around trying responsive CSS, and I made a menu with an ul, but the indentation keeps messing with my grid layout. The solution that I've found in several questions is adding list-style-type:none; padding: 0; and list-style-position:inside; but I still get the padding. This is my code:

```
                        <div class="row">
<div id="header" class="col-12">

<h1>Hey</h1>

</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
<div id="menu" class="col-3">
    <ul>
        <li>MENÚ 1</li><li>MENÚ 2</li><li>MENÚ 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content" class="col-6">
    <h2>Sup?</h2>
    <p> Content goes here </p>
</div>
<div id="sidebar" class="col-3">
    <p>This is a sidebar!</p>
</div>
                        </div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
*
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px)
{
    .col-1{width:8.33%;}
    .col-2{width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3{width:25%;}
    .col-4{width:33.33%;}
    .col-5{width:41.66%;}
    .col-6{width: 50%;}
    .col-7{width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8{width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9{width: 75%;}
    .col-10{width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11{width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12{width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px)
{
    li a
    {
        display: block;
    }
}

.row::after
{
    content: "";
    clear:both;
    display:table;
}
#menu ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#menu li
{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

And yet, I keep getting the ul padding that messes with the grid count and makes my #sidebar appear below:
[CSS trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkDZ3.png)

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: Added grid CSS

Comment: Can you include the grid CSS code? We can't solve a grid problem with only one item of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `[class*="col-"]`. Your problem is caused by wrong calculation of the padding with the width. this property will fix this as shown below:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .col-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .col-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
    li a {
        display: block;
    }
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="header" class="col-12">

        <h1>Hey</h1>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="menu" class="col-3">
        <ul>
            <li>MENÚ 1</li>
            <li>MENÚ 2</li>
            <li>MENÚ 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="col-6">
        <h2>Sup?</h2>
        <p> Content goes here </p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" class="col-3">
        <p>This is a sidebar!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **border-box:** The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

**To:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks!